# Python: How to get next k consecutive elements of an array each time?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am attempting to extract an array of **next** *K* consecutive items from a larger array of *nK + d* elements. Where *0 < d <= K* and *n >= 0*. In other words, in first attempt I would get Array[:K], then the next time  Array[K:2K] and so on. In the last iteration all the remaining elements Array[nK:nK+d], even if the number of items left is less than K. In all these previous operations, it is preferable that the original array stays intact.

For Example:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> k_items = get_next_k(arr, k = 3)
>>> print(k_items)
  [1, 2, 3]
>>> k_items = get_next_k(arr, k = 3)
>>> print(k_items)
  [4, 5, 6]
>>> k_items = get_next_k(arr, k = 3)
>>> print(k_items)
  [7, 8, 9]
>>> k_items = get_next_k(arr, k = 3)
>>> print(k_items)
  [10]
>>> print(arr)
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Is there a simple and efficient way to acheve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little brain-storming and web research, I got an idea that solves my problem with some degree of simplicity....

My code: (`get_k.py`)

```
class klist(list):
    curKidx = 0

    def get_next_k(self, k = 1):
        list_len = self.__len__()
        if (self.curKidx + k) > list_len:
            k = list_len - self.curKidx
        retKlist = [list.__getitem__(self, idx) for idx in range( self.curKidx, (self.curKidx + k) )]
        self.curKidx = self.curKidx + k
        return retKlist

a = klist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
print( a.get_next_k(3) )
print( a.get_next_k(3) )
print( a.get_next_k(3) )
print( a.get_next_k(3) )
```

Output:

```
# ./get_k.py 
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[0]
```

Also, one of the greatest flexibility here is, I can modify value of K in each call.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) with generator expression

```
from itertools import islice

def get_next_k(curr, k):
    return list(islice(curr, k))

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
curr = (x for x in arr)

for i in range(4):
    print(get_next_k(curr, 3))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```

Comment: I'd add that the `curr` is a generator and it will be exhausted using the `get_next`, so you can only run through it once, unless you create another generator.

Comment: op doesn't mention anything about if the end of array is reached

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
import math
def get_next_k(arr,k,idx):
  return arr[k*idx:k*idx+k]

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
k = 3
no_of_iters = int(math.ceil(float(len(arr))/k))
for i in range(no_of_iters):
  print(get_next_k(arr,k,i)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```